# Django Serializer - How to know which parameters was input wrongly

Tags: python, django, django-serializer

I always put `serializers` in an `try` statement that returns `false` when have invalid format.

Like this:

Sample model:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class CommentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    email = serializers.EmailField()
    content = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)
    created = serializers.DateTimeField()
```

Sample code:

```
try:
    testSerializer(data = b).is_valid()
except:
    return  HttpResponse("Invalid data type input)
```

Now, I want to `return` parameters was input incorrectly like this:

> Parameters: Name, Email was input in wrong type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `.errors`, this is a dictionary that maps the names of the fields to a list of errors:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

serializer = testSerializer(data=b)
if not serializer.is_valid():
    return  JsonResponse({'errors': serializer.errors}, status_code=400)
```

Note that `.is_valid()` does *not* raise an exception, it returns a boolean that is `True` in case the input was valid and `False` otherwise. You can raise an exception with the serializer by using the [**`raise_exception=True`** parameter [drf-doc]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#raising-an-exception-on-invalid-data), this will then raise a `Http400` error.